# php joining similar results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a php notification system (kinda like facebook's).

It works as should, listing all events the way i want it. but i'm trying to get it to understand that if it gets 3+ events on the same post, it will join these events into one notification.

Now it looks like this:

```
User 1 wrote on article-x
User 2 wrote on article-x
user 3 wrote on article-x
user 1 wrote on article-y
```

instead i want it to be printed like this :

```
user 1 and  2 others wrote on article-x
```

Been trying to read up on what i need to do this, but no luck. any pointers greatly appreciated.
It's being queried like this:

*edited with full code*

```
$sesname = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$sesid = $_SESSION['full_name'];
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from comments WHERE full_name = '$sesid' and checked ='1' ");
$stmt->bindParam(':full_name', $safe_name, PDO::PARAM_INT, 5);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt -> fetchAll();
foreach( $result as $row ) {
$name = $row['name'];
$pid = $row['pid'];
$commentid = $row['id'];
$fullink = $row['fullink'];
$datetime = $row['dt'];

if ($name == $sesname){
} else {
echo "<div id='commentnote'><a href='http://{$fullink}'>{$name}</a>kommenterte ditt <a href='{$fullink}'>blogginnlegg</a><br><div class='updentry' style='color: red ! important; cursor: pointer; margin-top: -35px; position: absolute; right: 8px;'>x</div></div>";
}

}
```

Tried using your answers underneath, but without luck. Thanks for answering though, i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

What about turning the article into a multidimensional array? (Just an example, structure isn't optimal since I don't know what data you have and need.)

```
if(count($post['comments']) >= 3) {
   echo $post['user'][0] ."and". (count($post['comments'])-1). " others wrote on ..";
} else {
   //Just one 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a 2-dimensional array  like this:

```
Array
(
    [article-x] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => User1
                       [1] => User2
                   )
    [article-y] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => User1
                   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in PHP, do something like this:

```
$events = array();
foreach( $result as $row ) {
    if( isset($events[$row['article']) ){
        $events[$row['article']]['counter']++;
    }else{
        $row['counter'] = 0;
        $events[$row['article']] = $row;
    }
}

foreach( $events as $event ){
    echo "<div id='commentnote'>{$event['user']}".($event['counter']?' and '.$event['counter'].' others':'')." wrote on {$event['article']}</div>";
}
```